# Why The New York Times no longer capitalizes "E-mail"

Tags: orthography, capitalization

Why isn't *E-mail* capitalized like it used to be in The New York Times?

Comment: Probably for the same reason "RADAR" is almost always written as "radar."  That is, because it's fallen into common use.

Comment: I still write "_e-mail_" with the hyphen, though. :)

Comment: English language changes over time, and convention or common usage sometimes trump _technically_ proper grammar. I wouldn't be surprised if they eventually shifted to just plain **email**... that's the form I prefer anyways.

Answer (score 4):

The 'E' part is an abbreviation, which tend to be capitalised, especially, as others have said, when it's a new term. And abbreviations, through popular use, eventually become a noun in their own right.

However, T-shirt seems to have resisted being lower cased for some decades now, other than the solitary 'tee' which I sometimes see in clothes shops. I wonder whether it's because we like to see the shape of the shirt in the 'T'.

In the UK, about 10 years ago a court order called an 'Anti-Social Behaviour Order' was created - and received many mentions in newspapers. They quickly evolved from ASBO through Asbo to asbo. I think the word was finally integrated when it became, at least in speech, a verb, ie you could have your neighbour 'asboed'.

Comment: Just a guess: T-shirt isn't lower-cased because the "T" physically resembles the shirt. A "t-shirt" would look like a hoodie. :-) Also, +1.

Comment: Have to say, I still only ever see 'ASBO' written as fully-capitalised in the papers. (Except when used as a verb, but newspapers tend to avoid that.)

Comment: @scottishwildcat The [Guardian style guide](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/a) says: *Use all capitals if an abbreviation is pronounced as the individual letters: BBC, VAT, etc; if it is an acronym (pronounced as a word) spell out with initial capital, eg Nasa, Nato, unless it can be considered to have entered the language as an everyday word, such as awol, laser and, more recently, **asbo**, pin number and sim card.* They also use *email* and *T-shirt*.

Comment: All these have to do with the shape, hence they remain capitalized: A-frame, C-clamp, I-beam, L-bracket, O-ring, S-curve, T-shirt, T-square, T-junction, T-bar, U-turn, V-neck, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find anything to verify this, but I think they capitalized it for the same reasons they still capitalize 'Web' and 'Internet' -- they considered it a proper name. Probably even when they did capitalize 'E-mail', they wouldn't have capitalized it in cases like "Sally received an e-mail," but only in cases like "The E-mail servers crashed in Barbados."

Comment: Looking through some other materials, I see that the old-school way to refer to _an_ email was "E-mail _message_."

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have happened around the turn of the millenium; there's mostly *E-mail* up to [1999](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nytimes.com/1999%20intext:%22e-mail%22), and *e-mail* from [2000](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nytimes.com/1999%20intext:%22e-mail%22).

Readers had been complaining about *E-mail* since at least 1995, which gives us the reasoning behind the capital. From the *New York Times*, [August 21, 1995](http://www.nytimes.com/1995/08/21/business/an-e-mail-by-any-other-name-might-sound-better.html?pagewanted=2):

> P.S. A recurrent gripe, regardless of the vote being cast, involved The New York Times style for writing "E-mail."
>
> "My biggest complaint is the fuddy-duddy spelling 'E-mail,' " wrote Cate Gable of Berkeley, Calif., speaking for many, who wonder why this newspaper uses an uppercase "E" for something that many people and publications write as "e-mail."
>
> **The Times style for the term is in keeping with T-shirt, A-frame, H-bomb and other analogous words that predate E-mail**. For now, at least, it will stay that way.

In fact, if you read the article from [page 1](http://www.nytimes.com/1995/08/21/business/an-e-mail-by-any-other-name-might-sound-better.html), they're discussing whether *An E-mail* and *E-mails* are acceptable terms for *a piece* and *pieces of electronic mail*.

Back to the present. The *New York Times* is still using *e-mail* and aren't planning to switch to *email* [just yet](http://topics.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/03/22/the-latest-in-style/). But more and more newspaper style guides, including the AP Stylebook, are dropping the hyphen. I expect the *Times* will follow at some point.

Answer (score 0):

It has become an independent word (they dropped the hyphen, too, from what I can see), not a hyphenated abbreviation of "electronic mail".

Comment: I'm not sure this answers why the capitalization has changed.  "Internet" has always been a single word, but it used be *the* Internet and now it's just the internet. So independence isn't enough to determine this.

Comment: @Matthew Read, the _New York Times_ still capitalizes 'Internet.' [At least sometimes](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/25/technology/25tech.html?scp=3&sq=internet&st=cse). But that doesn't have to do with 'independence' -- it's because they consider 'Internet' a proper noun.

Comment: @senderle That's exactly my point, it has nothing to do with independence. As per your answer, it could have something to do with E-mail also being considered a proper name.

Comment: I think you're right about the reason for the capitalization, that it followed the style they used for Internet and Web. But I was addressing the question asked: "why was the capitalization dropped?" Or did they spell it "Email" for a while? I figure they dropped the capital when they dropped the hyphen.

Comment: "it used be the Internet and now it's just the internet". You still have *the* in there. Or did you mean that *the* was part of the name? I don't see any difference between then and now.

Comment: @Arlen Beiler, he was referring to the change in capitalization.

Comment: @JeffSahol NYT are still using the [hyphen](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27506/the-ny-times-once-capitalized-e-mail-why-is-it-no-longer-capitalized/48252#48252).